# Flex stack columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What is the best method to make `flex` column's stack in terms of screen responsivity sizes?

Below I tried to add a responsive query to change the flex column to the value of two, but it didnt seem to do the trick.

```css
.blurb-container {
  display: flex;
}

.blurb-half-column {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.blurb-container>div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .blurb-half-column {
    flex: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blurb-container">
  <div class="blurb-half-column">
    <p class="justify">Once you have completed your training and you have been certificated, we ask that you submit the required amount of ‘post training in clinic evidence’ and case studies within a 2 month period. This may be in the form of witness statements, client
      testimonials, photographic evidence, and reflection. You will learn more about post study on your training days and you will be provided with a work study pack to assist you.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blurb-half-column">
    <p class="justify">This course is for CTIA members only (please see our members section). It can be taken alongside basic Wrinkle Relaxing training or as a stand-alone course.</p>
    <p class="justify">This course price is discounted if taken alongside the basic module.</p>
    <p class="justify">*Please note all prices quoted for training are exclusive of VAT. VAT is 20% of any course quotations and is to be added to cost.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check the `flex-wrap` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.blurb-container{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.blurb-half-column{
   width: 50%;
}
@media(max-width: 414px){
  .blurb-half-column{
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

By simply adding the flex-wrap attribute combined with a width on the columns you  can achieve what you asked for.
The same would work with "min-width" instead. With min-width you don´t even need mediaqueries.

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why - don't just answer with code pastes

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `flex-wrap` and `min-width` for your element

```css
.blurb-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.blurb-half-column {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 40px;
  min-width:300px;
}

.blurb-container>div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurb-container">
  <div class="blurb-half-column">
    <p class="justify">Once you have completed your training and you have been certificated, we ask that you submit the required amount of ‘post training in clinic evidence’ and case studies within a 2 month period. This may be in the form of witness statements, client
      testimonials, photographic evidence, and reflection. You will learn more about post study on your training days and you will be provided with a work study pack to assist you.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blurb-half-column">
    <p class="justify">This course is for CTIA members only (please see our members section). It can be taken alongside basic Wrinkle Relaxing training or as a stand-alone course.</p>
    <p class="justify">This course price is discounted if taken alongside the basic module.</p>
    <p class="justify">*Please note all prices quoted for training are exclusive of VAT. VAT is 20% of any course quotations and is to be added to cost.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```